# preg_match(): Compilation failed: unrecognized character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, special-characters

Sorry for my english.

```
$string = "product#[:id]#[:str]";

$regex = preg_replace("/\[:(\w+)\]/", "(?<$1>.+?)", $string);
```

What I get is `product#(?.+?)#(?.+?)`  instead of  `product#(?<id>.+?)#(?<str>.+?)`

I want to do that because I need preg_match() to create key names in $matches:

```
preg_match('/^'. $regex .'$/', str_replace("/", "#", self::$path), $matches)
```

The point is, it works without '<' and '>'. But I need them for next code.
So what should I do about these '<', '>' chars? I need them but don't know what to do. I also tried to escape them: \<  (But no results).

Please help me if you have any ideas.

## Edit:

Seems like what I did was ok.
Now there's new problem:

```
$string = "product#[i:id]#[*:str]";

$regex = preg_replace("/\[i:(\w+)\]/", "(?<$1>[0-9]+)", $regex);
$regex = preg_replace("/\[\*:(\w+)\]/", "(?<$1>.+?)", $regex);
```

No I tried something else and this doesn't work. Why? :(

Comment: Are you sure? https://3v4l.org/XK3L6

Comment: Are you sure? This should work just fine, as shown in [this demo](https://3v4l.org/5du4h). If you're just `echo`ing it to a browser, your browser is hiding the `<id`> and `<str>` from you because they look like HTML tags. They're there in the source; you just don't see them in the rendered HTML.

Comment: It seems code is working

Comment: Thank you. You are right. Awesome. :)

Comment: @ValentinTanasescu You should explain what chars `str` and `id` can contain. `.+?` at the end of the pattern only matches 1 char and is rather useless. Also, why not use `str_replace('[i:id]', '(?<id>\d+)',$s)` and `str_replace('[*:str]', '(?<id>\w+)',$s)`?

Comment: Probably, you should ask a new question and this one should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Please don't change the question after people have answered it. Ask a new question if you have a new question. Also, please explain *what* doesn't work in your code. "This doesn't work" isn't enough information for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result of your `preg_replace` is to be rendered in a browser,
and just this **rendered** result should contain `<` and `>` chars,
then you should generate them as `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

So maybe your replacement string (2nd argument of `preg_replace`) should be:

```
(?&lt;$1&gt;.+?)
```

Comment: A better approach is to generate the correct string (with `<`, `>`, and whatever other special characters are needed), then use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) when displaying it on-screen.